# Object ref not set to instance of object in SPListItem extension method

Tags: visual-studio, splistitem

I am attempting to write an extension method for the SPListItem type to ease the pain of getting SPUserValues as strings. I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception when I hit the line:
`msg = "field.AllowMultipleValues == " + field.AllowMultipleValues;`

because `field` is null. I know that at the item level `item[fieldName]` has a value and that the field does exist as I can see the field definition in `item.Fields`.

Any suggestions about where I am going wrong?

```
    public static List<string> GetFieldValueUserLogin(this SPListItem item, string fieldName)
    {     

        try
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("_PAR_", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, "Getting value of " + fieldName, null);
                List<string> userNames = new List<string>();

                SPFieldUser field = item[fieldName] as SPFieldUser;

                string msg = field == null ? "field is null" : "field is not null";

                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("_PAR_", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, msg, null);

                msg = "field.AllowMultipleValues == " + field.AllowMultipleValues;

                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("_PAR_", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, msg, null);

//Etc ...
   }
}
```

Edit---
After a bit of caffeine I went back and realized I was kind of being an idiot. Appears to be my modus operandi. Here is my final method code.

```
public static List<string> GetFieldValueUserLogins(this SPListItem item, string fieldName)
{
    try
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            List<string> userNames = new List<string>();

            SPFieldUserValueCollection uvc = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(item.Web, item[fieldName].ToString());
            foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in uvc)
            {
                userNames.Add(userValue.User.LoginName);
            }


            return userNames;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("_PAR_", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Information), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace.ToString(), null);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be honest I'm really confused with your code because your method name implies you are getting a value but the code looks like you are reading and possibly updating a field property. So to provide some feedback on the code you have there:

As you stated, `item[fieldDisplayName]` will get you a field value. (SPFieldUserValue, SPFieldUserValueCollection, string, etc.)

`item.Fields[fieldInternalName]` is what you need to get you a field. (SPField, SPFieldUser, SPFieldChoice, etc.)

Once you have the field, to get the value I would use the field Id and cast your values accordingly using `item[field.Id]` - this will eliminate any discrepencies / confusion between "should I now use the internal or display name?"

Comment: item.Fields[fieldInternalName] <= Exactly that. But, no I was not updating any value in my code. The idea was just to return a list of user names.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to cast it as an SPFieldUserValue or an SPFieldUserValueCollection?

Comment: That is not possible as I am dealing with the field object. `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUser` inherits from `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField` and neither `SPFieldUserValue` nor `SPFieldUserValueCollection` are field types.

Comment: item[fieldName] or item[fieldGuid] won't give you a field, it will give you a field value.

Comment: aditionally you could do
SPFieldUserValueCollection users = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(item.Web, item[field].ToString())
and iterate trough the SPFieldValue collection

Comment: @Jaime - don't forget you can edit your answer if you want to expand on it, as well as adding comments.

Comment: @Jaime - +1'ed your answer because you were right as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

1. Always using the InternalName of the field
2. Try validating the collection of Fields via spList.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName)

Comment: I pass the internal name as the parameter `fieldName`.

Answer (score 0):

As C. Marius you need to lookup the internal name as it would have some other long values attached to it..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.aspx

plus try this instead

```
SPFieldUser field =(SPFieldUser)item[fieldName];
```

also field.AllowMultipleValues shouldnt it be set i belive to true or false?

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether multiple values
>   can be used in the lookup field.
>
> true to specify that multiple values can be used in the field;
>   otherwise, false. The default is false.

like so:

```
field.AllowMultipleValues = true;
```

or

```
field.AllowMultipleValues = false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.allowmultiplevalues(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: You are not understanding the line `msg = "field.AllowMultipleValues == " + field.AllowMultipleValues;` this will print the string `field.AllowMultipleValues == true` or `field.AllowMultipleValues == false` to the ULS. I'm just throwing in some debugging so I can go back after the fact and make sure values are set as expected.